# Untrusted Walkthrough

Tags: discussion

Would it be considered bad form to post my Untrusted answers for levels I have completed so far? I know questions have been asked here about the tag and our own Agent86 has answered on one or two.

Is it OK to open an Untrusted question with a full walkthrough. I have reached level 11, I could post my results till Level 11 that are linked on GitHub.

I do know we do not do walkthroughs.

But I would like us to be the best gaming source on the net. If that means post the solutions then I dunno.

I am having fun in the game, so would not want someone else to be able to not enjoy the game.

What does the community think?

Comment: I think it's a bit too broad and people are unlikely to need or even want all the solutions at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are not a site that does walkthroughs.  We help users answer questions.  If they want help on every level, then they can ask for every level.

If we begin accepting full games, then how to we draw the line?  Can I ask/answer a full walkthrough of [candy-box](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/candy-box)? How about [portal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal)?  Maybe [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim)?

All of Stack Exchange is striving to be the source for information, but we do not want to do the work for everyone.  Stack Overflow does not write the code for you.  They take your attempt and improve it or offer suggestions.  We do not play the game for you.  You tell us where you are stuck and we help you get past it.

We also do not want to encourage users to not look for themselves.  Otherwise, why would the even bother searching Arqade to see if their question was asked before?

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Many browser games I play tend to end up being... *modified* when I play them.  Candy-box and cookie-clicker are a few of the more recent ones.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ In response to your comment [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163480/how-to-use-the-phone/163489?noredirect=1#comment219502_163489), the reason we do not include every level is because we do not need to.  If you feel a level was difficult for you and other users would benefit from an answer, then by all means ask and answer.  I did that for the [robot maze](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163507/how-can-i-get-this-robot-to-finish-the-maze).  Otherwise, If a user comes and asks, we will be more than happy to help them.

Answer (score 3):

There's a reason users can ask and self-answer questions.  If you believe the problem you're running into will happen to more people, that's exactly what it's for.

That said, walkthroughs as a whole don't work very well here.  They're too general.  We're more about specific problems, with specific answers to those problems.

We already have several questions about specific levels.  What would a general question do to those?  I would much prefer questions about levels, not a single whole walkthrough.

Comment: By general, I mean that readers have to dig through the answer to find the part they're looking for.  That's the same problems forums have; we're about providing narrowly focused answers to specific questions.